# How can I duplicate items on join

Tags: join, oracle11g

I have 2 tables.

```
TableA
ID | ColA | ColB
1  | asd  | x
2  | qwe  | z
3  | poi  | w

TableB
ID | ColC | ColD | ColE
1  | rty  | z    | 123
2  | fgh  | x    | 276
3  | rtyy | z    | 657
```

and I'm using this SQL

```
SELECT bb.colc, aa.cola FROM tableA aa, tableb bb
WHERE aa.colb = bb.cold
```

and getting this result

```
Result
ID | ColA | ColC
1  | asd  | fgh
2  | qwe  | rty
3  | qwe  | rtyy
```

I know this is correct, but how can I do not duplicate 'qwe' line?

For me the line from TableB that is used is irrelevant.

Comment: as u hav two values 'z' in ur ColD its returning two rows

Comment: The 'qwe' line is not a duplicate of any other line in your results.

Comment: What criteria should you use to determine which of both `qwe` rows should be kept and which not shown in the result?

Comment: @Marc, for me id 2 and 3 is duplicated because 'rty' and 'rtyy' is same information.

Comment: @Mosty, is not important to me which line is used but I need only one line.

Comment: But "rty" != "rtyy".  So you haven't answered @MostyMostacho's question.  Why are you even selecting a value you don't care about into your resultset?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select tb1.colc, ta1.cola from (
  select max(id) id, max(colc) as colc, cold from tb
  group by cold
) tb1
join ta ta1 on ta1.colb = tb1.cold
```

Let me know if this is what you expected.

Comment: this query not work because 'rty' is different from 'rtyy'. To remove a duplicate line, all values from distinct cols need to be the same. hehe :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you just want:

```
   SELECT aa.id, aa.cola 
     FROM tableA aa
    WHERE aa.colB in (Select bb.cold from tableb bb);
```

That's probably not the most efficient efficient way to do it, but is that the resultset you're looking for?

Comment: Your comments above suggested you don't actually care what's in column C!

Answer (score 0):

This query will choose just one COLC entry for you by usng the `max` function:

```
SELECT aa.id,
       aa.cola,
       Max(bb.colc),
  FROM tableA aa,
       tableb bb
 WHERE aa.colb = bb.cold
 GROUP BY aa.id,
          aa.cola;
```